# How does Lucene scoring work in regard to queries?

Tags: lucene, lucene.net, tf-idf

I understand that the default scoring function uses TF*IDF or a similar variant thereof. However, it is unclear to me how this works on queries, e.g. `BooleanQuery`.

Say I create a `BooleanQuery` with many `TermQuery`s with `Occur.SHOULD`. Is the TF of the query as a whole considered? E.g. if my `BooleanQuery` contains two `TermQuery`s with the term "hello", the TF for "hello" would be high in the query itself. Is that considered? Or is only the different TF in regard to individual documents considered?

Looking at the source code for `MoreLikeThis(...)`, it seems to consider the TF in the query itself. Are there similar classes in Lucene that does this, or do all queries do this?